# How can i overlay an 10x10px image on top of another image?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have a user avatar on my website. Simple image tag:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" class="userphoto" width="48" height="48" alt="">
```

Now, i want to *float* an image (Facebook Icon - 10x10px) over this image on the top left corner of the image.

This is to signify that the user is authenticated to Facebook.

How can i do this? CSS styling on the image tag, or will i have to have a seperate div with absolute positioning?

Doesn't need to be transparent or anything, just needs to be positioned exactly in the top-left corner.

Of course i cant just physically modify the image, as i need to determine whether to overlay the image dynamically based on the Facebook status. But i was hoping to dynamically add a css class.

Any ideas?

**ANSWER:**

Got it working with a combination of both answers. Used a div instead of another image.

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
   <div class="fboverlay"></div>
   <a>
      <img src="foo.jpg" class="userphoto" width="48" height="48" alt="">
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}

.fboverlay
{
    background-image: url('/image/facebook/logo.gif');
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know I'm not using the exact dimensions you wanted, but here's a working example for you. (You would need the parent ".main_photo" div to be the dimensions of the main photo.)

```css
.main_photo{
    position:relative;
    width:80px;
    height:80px
}
.inlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px
}
```

```html
<div class="main_photo">
    <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=200&d=mm&r=pg" />
    <img class="inlay" src="https://www.rit.edu/news/lib/views/public/images/dateline_images/facebook_icon.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: Got it working with that relevant example. Thanks!

Comment: This can be improved so that you don't have to specify the div's width and height: http://jsfiddle.net/robcampo/ny4TB/1/

Comment: Just a link without any code is not great...

Answer (score 3):

First you have to `position` it - either relative or absolute usually.

Secondly, you have to set a `z-index` if there are other positioned elements, though you may not necessarily need one.

Using `top/left` or `bottom/right` combinations layer the image over the other one.

This is advice without seeing any html/css. It will obviously differ depending on the situation.

```
#el-on-top { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1; }
```

You may need to set `position:relative` so the AP'd element's top is relative to something, instead of say, the wrapper or the entire page.

Comment: thanks, i've showed you the HTML though. the CSS for 'usephoto' is very simple - vertical-align: middle and position: relative.

any chance you can update your answer with some code? i was looking for advice as to whether i need a seperate div tag with the overlayed image, or can i do it all with some CSS directly applied to the img tag?

Comment: That's a snippet of the HTML. Considering that's one line of HTML, it's hard to determine the structure, which is vital in regards to the stacking order and layering ( z-index ). Though in general, just AP the image and use top/left, should be good enough. It would help if you setup a jsfiddle.

Comment: The problem with these answers is that the style element, "position" is not supported by the following email clients: Outlook 2007/10/13 iPhone iOS 7/iPad (position: fixed; does not result in elements being positioned relative to the reading pane)
Yahoo! Mail
Google Gmail Source: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/