# Overlaying text on the upper right corner of a background image

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how is it possible to achieve notification count as we see in linked (as shown in image below)

[image]

I have tried implementing a similar solutions, using a Span which has a background image and then using  tag along with it.

Roughly,

```
<span class="message-icon" title="Unread Message" style="display: inline-block"></span><span style="background-color: red"><sup><b>5</b></sup></span>
```

this is no where near to what is there on linkedin's site.

Is there a cooked solution already available for it? Or any Ideas how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/D3VVv/1/
From this post: [How can i overlay an 10x10px image on top of another image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393045/how-can-i-overlay-an-10x10px-image-on-top-of-another-image)

If you make the div that contains the message icon as big as the message icon + the notification icon, then you can position the notification icon in the top right corner of that div using `absolute` positioning. As is shown in the fiddle.

Comment: I want to overlay text on an image. Not an image on an image.

Comment: Please disregard my above comments and thanks for that example. I got it working using that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, here is an example of absolute positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/e2Zs4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="con">

<img src="http://www.pictures-of-kittens-and-cats.com/images/cute-kitten-pictures-002-small.jpg" />

<img class ="number" src="http://www.privatefly.com/export/PrivateFly/.content/images/services/red_numbers_4.gif " />

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.con { width:100px; height:100px; position:relative; }
.number { position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px; }
```

Comment: Ok the cat is nice, but that example is exactly the same as in the question i refered to, maybe we should file this question as duplicate...

Comment: @saratis, sorry mate, didn't see your post until I had posted.